# Update multiple column based on condition

Tags: sql, syntax, sql-update, amazon-redshift

I have the following queries:

```
update a
set dwc=fa.dwc
from b fa
join a mw
on a.fa_state=b.state
where b.dwc=''
;
update a
set dwa=fa.dwa
from b fa
join a mw
on a.fa_state=b.state
where b.dwa=''
```

I am trying to combine into one- is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have several column clauses in the `set` clause. You just need to separate them by a comma (`,`):

```
update a
set dwc=fa.dwc, dwa=fa.dwa -- Here!
from b fa
join a mw
on a.fa_state=b.state
where b.dwc=''
```

Comment: No idea how I missed that in documentation. Thank you!